# redux-sagas does not dispatch action when firebase cloud function is complete

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, redux-saga

this function  calls firebase cloud function

```
   function createUser (data3){
      var addUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('crearPaquete');
      addUser(data3).then(function(result) {
     // Read result of the Cloud Function.


      return result //return uid inserted

    }).catch(function(error) {
  // Getting the Error details.
  var code = error.code;
  var message = error.message;
  var details = error.details;
  // ...
});

}
```

then I call function createUser inside redux-saga function

```
export function* createPackageStart({payload}){

try {
 
 
 yield  user= **createUser(payload)**
  if(user.data){
     yield put(createPackageSuccess()). **///this never is dispatch**


 }

 } catch(error){
    yield  put(createPackageFailure(error))


   }
}
```

I need the result of cloud function to dispatch success action but "user" variable never gets update with cloud function result

How can I achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `addUser` function performs an asynchronous operation. With your current code, Cloud Functions terminates the container for your code when the last `}` has executed, which is before the asynchronous function has completed. To make the container wait, you need to return a promise.

```
function createUser(data3) {
    var addUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('crearPaquete');
    return addUser(data3).then(function(result) {
        // Read result of the Cloud Function.


        return result //return uid inserted

    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Getting the Error details.
        var code = error.code;
        var message = error.message;
        var details = error.details;
        // ...
    });

}
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [sending back the result](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result)